# Write in realtime database with android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting into this about the app, I want to register users and save them in firebase. This is my code:

```
package com.example.jimax_project;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class AuthActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText mEditTextName;
private EditText mEditTextEmail;
private EditText mEditTextPassword;


//TAGS DE LOS DATOS A REGISTRAR;
private String name= "";
private String email= "";
private String password= "";

FirebaseAuth mAuth;
DatabaseReference mDatabase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_auth);

    Button mButtonRegister;

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    mEditTextName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    mEditTextEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditTextEmail);
    mEditTextPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditTextPassword);
    mButtonRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

    mButtonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            name = mEditTextName.getText().toString();
            email = mEditTextEmail.getText().toString();
            password = mEditTextPassword.getText().toString();

            if (!name.isEmpty() && !email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()){
                if(password.length()>=6) {
                    registerUser();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(AuthActivity.this,"La contraseña debe tener almenos 6 caracteres",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(AuthActivity.this,"Debe completar los campos",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
private void registerUser(){
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){

                Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("name",name);
                map.put("email",email);
                map.put("password",password);

                String id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

                mDatabase.child("Users").child(id).setValue(map).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task2) {
                        if (task2.isSuccessful()){
                            startActivity(new Intent(AuthActivity.this,ProfileActivity.class));
                            finish();
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(AuthActivity.this,"No se puedieron crear los datos correctamente",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(AuthActivity.this,"No se pudo registrar el usuario",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

the problem is that when you press the register button, the authentication is done in firebase but the data is not registered in the database (users table) that the app should create

When I press "Register" button, that apears in the Log:

```
2021-09-07 15:03:56.998 7135-7299/com.example.jimax_project W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
2021-09-07 15:03:58.344 7135-7299/com.example.jimax_project W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
2021-09-07 15:03:58.649 7135-7299/com.example.jimax_project D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( B3G6IL3ThuXk0OrO32uA9QKcgMz2 ).
2021-09-07 15:03:58.650 7135-7299/com.example.jimax_project D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying auth state listeners about user ( B3G6IL3ThuXk0OrO32uA9QKcgMz2 ).
```

I've been looking for, and I have the security set to true in the firebase, I have tried adding the android line: usesCleartextTraffic = "true" in the manifest and I also have the internet permissions declared, I don't know what else I can test.

I would appreciate any kind of help, Thanks

Comment: Is your onComplete even triggered? Have you tried to see what happens if the Task is not successful?

Comment: It seems to me that no, at least it does not change the activity as it would have to do when registering the user. What's more, I have put a Toast inside the first Oncomplete, when I press register for the first time it does nothing, when I press for the second time, the toast message appears followed by the message that says "it could not be registered" (Because it already exists the user in authentication)

Comment: Do you have the proper rules to write in your database?

Comment: I have this rules in firebase:   "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }

Comment: What's your database location? Europe?

Comment: Yes, the default location for CGP resources is eur 3 (west-europe)

Answer (score 1):

Your 'name', 'email', and 'password' are not Objects, they are String.
You must use String in your map, not Object.
See below:
`Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();` - Wrong
`Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();` - Correct

Replace your 'Object' with 'String' and everything should work fine.
Thanks

Comment: Good afternoon, I have changed the object to string but it still does not work correctly. The activity app does not change and the message "Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null." in the log

Comment: You can make your own Object. Put values in that object and push the object in your database.